# Facebook search manipulates keywords

Tags: facebook, api, search

When using the Facebook Graph API to search through public posts, it seems like Facebook malforms search terms in ways that are not obvious. For example, searching for 'coffee' will return only posts containing 'coffe' (mind the e). When searching for certain plural words ending with 's', Facebook removes the 's'. The problem now is that searching for certain non-English terms such as 'Wilders' (name of a person), will return results for the English word 'wilder'.

This has been asked to Facebook dev support but they claim it to be 'by design'. If this is by design however, I am wondering how I can actually search for 'coffee', 'carrots' or 'wilders' without getting my search terms malformed.

See also http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/336651873112920 and http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/591586327522090

Answer (score -2):

If the last letter of each search word will be cut off, then try to add always one letter at the end of every word.

Comment: That's the problem, it does not always happen. For example, searching for 'coffeee' to find 'coffee' works, but searching for 'wilderss' to find 'wilders' does not work - it returns no results.